# Recognize when a database connection happens in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, odbc

I have the shiny app below which consists of `app.r` and `global.r`. The global file includes the code that enables a database connection. This connenction is enabled via a big number of passwords which are known only from the database admin. So I want every time the user gives a wrong password a message to be displayed. For this question I just used a random password in order to create the `if else` statement but as I said above the connection happens with many different passwords so instead of setting all of those manually I would just like to recognize if the connection `con` happens.

**app.r**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
mytitle <- paste0("Life, Death & Statins")
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px"
)


shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px"
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
      
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
      passwordInput("pwd",label = "",value = "",width = "100%" ),
      actionButton('button', "Continue"),
      uiOutput("error")
    )
    
    
  ),
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      
      
      if(input$pwd==""){
        return(NULL)
      }
      else if(input$pwd=="qh2gt1"){
        return(NULL)
      }
      else{
        output$error<-renderUI({
          "Please re-enter database browser password"
        })
      }
      
      
      
    })
  }
  )
)
```

**global.r**

```
library(odbc) 
con<- dbConnect(odbc(),
                driver   = "SQL Server",
                database = "databasename",
                server   = svr,
                port     = 1433,
                UID      = "uid",
                PWD      = input$pwd)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encapsulate the `dbConnect` inside a `try` :

```
con <- try( dbConnect( odbc(),
                       driver   = "SQL Server",
                       database = "databasename",
                       server   = svr,
                       port     = 1433,
                       UID      = "uid",
                       PWD      = input$pwd))
```

Then check its `class`:

```
if( class(con) != "try-error" ) 
  # OK code
else
  # Error code
```